# Kubuntu 20.04 on Thinkpad X1 Carbon and no audio

Tags: drivers, sound, 20.04, kubuntu, thinkpad

I have recently installed Kubuntu 20.04 on my Lenovo Thinkpad X1 carbon and there is no sound from internal speakers. I have a Bluetooth headset and when testing the audio via Bluetooth HS works fine. Can someone please help me get sound working from builtin speakers.

**What I have tried so far without any usccess**

1. I have adjusted the settings in `alsamixer` as suggested [here by Giorgio Vitanza](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1129013/speakers-not-working-sunrise-point-lp-hd-audio) but it didn't work
2. I reinstalled `alsa` and `pulseaudio` as suggested by [Khalil in this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1245364/42509) but it didn't work
3. I updated `alsa-base.conf` to add `options snd-hda-intel model=generic` as suggested [by Mark X in this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1264125/42509) but it didn't work for me.
4. I updated `alsa-base.conf` to add `options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0` as suggested [by Leon X in this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1271458/42509) but it didn't work for me.

**My system details**

`$ uname -a`

```
Linux ThinkPad 5.4.0-52-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 15 10:57:00 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Running `sudo lshw -C multimedia` outputs

```
  *-multimedia
       description: Audio device
       product: Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
       version: 21
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=64
       resources: irq:136 memory:f1340000-f1343fff memory:f1330000-f133ffff
```

`$ lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"`

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 64, IRQ 136
        Memory at f1340000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Memory at f1330000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

Comment: Have you tried installing `sof-firmware`? That's how I fixed my issue on [ArchLinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lenovo_ThinkPad_X1_Carbon_(Gen_7)#Audio).

Comment: Thanks @antoyo Can you please advise me where to find this firmware?

Comment: I'm not sure whether there's already a package for Ubuntu. Maybe one of these links provide what you need: https://github.com/thesofproject/sof-bin https://github.com/thesofproject/sof/releases/

Comment: @KhurramMajeed What generation of X1 Carbon do you have? I have a 6th gen, and I have the same problem. Opened a bug report here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1290154/kubuntu-20-04-on-thinkpad-x1-carbon-and-no-audio

Comment: @mpenkov Mine is 4h gen